# Loop through my BindingList collection or the DataGridView to which it is bound

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, bindinglist

I've got a class that represents an XML file to be "processed". I've created a BindingList of these objects and bound it to a DataGridView so the user (i.e. me) can "control" things a bit and "see" what's happening. By default, the constructor assumes all files in the list will be "processed":

```
public class InputFileInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool processThisFile;
    public bool Process
    {
        get { return processThisFile; }
        set 
        {
            processThisFile = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Process");
        }
    }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    // constructor
    public InputFileInfo(string fName)
    {
        Process = true;
        FileName = fName;
        Rows = 0;
        Message = String.Empty;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The first column of the DGV called "Process" might become unchecked in which case I want to skip that file (i.e. row) and continue with the next. The last 2 columns of the DGV are intended to display the number of output **Rows** that were emitted out of the processed XML file and a place to put some sort of **Message** (such as "OK" or "error text").

In short, I want the DataGridView to be the visual representation of the process, echoing results in 2 little columns and allowing the user to skip a row by unchecking it.

Clicking on a **button** starts the processing of the files in the DGV. Here is what I have sketched so far (seems to work but the DGV does not reflect changes made in fileInfo.Rows and fileInfo.Message):

----- EDIT-UPDATE: per David Hall's suggestion, looping thru the BindingList (_filesToParse) is a good fix to this problem (working code follows):

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("output-file.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
        OutputColumnNamesAsFirstLine(writer);
        foreach (InputFileInfo fileInfo in _filesToParse)
        {
            if (fileInfo.Process == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileInfo.Rows = processFile(writer, fileInfo.FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Warn("Error processing DataGridView:\r\n", ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fileInfo.Rows = 0;
                fileInfo.Message = "skipped";
            }
        }
        writer.Dispose();
        fs.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("All selected files have been processed.");
    }
```

What would be the best approach?

- Loop through the BindingList ?
- Loop through the DataGridView ?

I think what I need is "two-way" binding but I maybe not? Am I close?

-----------------E D I T (UPDATE)----------------

Yes, the XML files already exist. Here is how that part works:

```
private void initializeFileList(string rootFolder) // populate grid with .xml filenames to be processed
    {
        String root = rootFolder;
        var result = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(name => new InputFileInfo(name))
                    .ToList();
        _filesToParse =  new BindingList<InputFileInfo>(result.ToList());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _filesToParse;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        btnProcess.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Does the xml file already exist externally? If so I'd consider using it to create a datatable - you can then add a boolean column to the datatable to allow for binding to the grid and during processing us dataviews to filter so you only have the selected items. Then do a foreach on the items in that view.

Comment: for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

Comment: And in answer to your original question - I would probably go with looping over the list (you can use a foreach loop btw on either the datagridview rows or the list items) mainly because that decouples your ui from you logic a little bit more. And yes, set up two way databinding for this.

Comment: @David: Shouldn't that be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @ChrisWue Yes and no - it is more an opinion and I haven't thought it through in too much depth. The question depends on a lot - John's preferences as much as anything else, so I felt more comfortable with a comment. Maybe in the morning I'll have thought through a proper answer.

Comment: @David: Please see Edit(Update) in the the original question. So looping over the BindingList is recommended...I am trying to decouple the UI from the logic (just want to echo results back to the UI and be responsive to the user UNCHECKING any given row).

Comment: @David: I did not consider creation of a datatable but I got this working by following your comment suggesting looping over the BindingList (edited code above showing the foreach loop in the btnProcess_click event works as shown). This all came together via another thread I posted regarding the "two-way" binding issue: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769154/how-to-use-a-static-utility-method-for-property-setters-in-a-utility-class

Comment: @John sounds good - I tried using datatables and found that the dataviews were not as powerful as I remembered, so I think looping over the bindinglist is the best option. Post this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Hall's comment(s) gave me enough confidence to go in this direction:

- leave the datagridview as is from the toolbox to the form (i.e. do NOT loop thru the DGV)
- loop thru the BindingList collection

I took a stab at this code and posted it above by EDITing the original post. The code works but the DGV does not reflect it properly.

So, this question morphed into a different question about how to achieve 2-way binding for a datagridview which I opened in (this new thread):[How to use a static utility method for property setters in a utility class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769154/how-to-use-a-static-utility-method-for-property-setters-in-a-utility-class)